# Geolocalização Mobile Cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que contem um cadastro do endereço que a pessoa se encontra, e gostaria de pegar estes dados direto do serviço de localização, porém gostaria de saber se teria como pegar o nome e numero da rua.
Já vi alguns exemplos na web que retornam a latitude e longitude mas existe como pegar o endereço?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, primeiramente é necessário adicionar ao seu projeto o [plugin de Geolocalização](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/), após esta etapa, você deve criar um arquivo do tipo *HTML* dentro da pasta *WWW* este arquivo poderá ser preenchido com o seguinte código:

HTML:

```
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cadastro de notificação</title>

    <!--ARQUIVO DE ESTILO, NECESSÁRIO PARA RENDERIZAR O MAPA-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css" />

    <!--SCRIPTS NECESSÁRIOS PARA A CRIAÇÃO DO MAPA-->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SUA_CHAVE_DA_API_GOOGLE_MAPS&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/maps.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- AO INICIAR O BODY, A FUNÇÃO INITMAP SERÁ EXECUTADA-->
<body onload="initMap()">
    <div id="map"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Lembrando que para utilizar a API do Google Maps, é necessário obter uma chave para uso através do site [da sua documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=pt-br).

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function initMap() {
var sucesso = function(position) { 
// váriavel que receberá as coordenadas obtidas através do seu dispositivo
    var coords = position.coords; 

// váriavel que recebe as funções do google maps
    var map = new google.maps.Map(

//busca no HTML o id da div
        document.getElementById("map"), {

// ao iniciar, o mapa será centralizado nas coordenadas obtidas
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude),
// definido o zoom do mapa
            zoom : 17, 
//não permite ao usuário mover o mapa
            draggable: false,
//desabilita o zoom quando ouver clique duplo 
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
//desabilita as interfaces de ferramentas padrão do google maps
            disableDefaultUI: true
        }
    );

//variável que receberá o marcador do google maps
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

//atribuição da posição do google maps através das coordenadas
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude)
    });
// define o marcador na div map
    marker.setMap(map);        
}


var erro = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Erro ao capturar posição: " + error.message, "INFORMAÇÃO");
}

// Opções para acessar o GPS...
var opcoes = {
    maximumAge: 3000,
    timeout: 5000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};

// CAPTURAR POSIÇÃO: Chamada a API de Geolocalização (GPS) via Apache Cordova
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sucesso, erro, opcoes);
}
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
 height: 250px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Geolocalização através de GPS do aparelho utilizando PhoneGap, API Google Maps e jQuery Mobile

API Geolocation do PhoneGap fornece informações sobre a localização do dispositivo, como a latitude e longitude, altitude, velocidade entre outras.

As fontes comuns de informação de localização incluem Sistema de Posicionamento Global (GPS) e localização inferida a partir de sinais de rede, como endereço IP, RFID, Wi-Fi e Bluetooth endereços MAC, e os IDs de células GSM / CDMA. Utilizou-se também o framework jQuery Mobile para exibir os conteúdos do app como cabeçalho, rodapé e conteúdo do mapa.

geomap.js:

```
/**
 * AppGeolocationMap
 */
var map;
var marker;
var infowindow;
var watchID;
var msg;
 
$(document).ready(function() {
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 // for testing in Chrome browser uncomment
 // onDeviceReady();
});
 
// PhoneGap is ready function
function onDeviceReady() {
 $(window).unbind();
 $(window).bind('pageshow resize orientationchange', function(e) {
  max_height();
 });
 max_height();
 google.load("maps", "3.8", {
  "callback" : map,
  other_params : "sensor=true&language=en"
 });
}
 
function max_height() {
 var h = $('div[data-role="header"]').outerHeight(true);
 var f = $('div[data-role="footer"]').outerHeight(true);
 var w = $(window).height();
 var c = $('div[data-role="content"]');
 var c_h = c.height();
 var c_oh = c.outerHeight(true);
 var c_new = w - h - f - c_oh + c_h;
 var total = h + f + c_oh;
 if (c_h < c.get(0).scrollHeight) {
  c.height(c.get(0).scrollHeight);
 } else {
  c.height(c_new);
 }
}
 
function map() {
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.9555, -53.4552);
 var myOptions = {
  zoom : 6,
  center : latlng,
  streetViewControl : true,
  mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  zoomControl : true
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
 
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
  // get geoposition once
  // navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error, {
  // maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
  // watch for geoposition change
  watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success, geo_error, {
   maximumAge : 5000,
   timeout : 5000,
   enableHighAccuracy : true
  });
 });
}
 
function geo_error(error) {
 // comment
 alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
 
function geo_success(position) {
 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
   position.coords.longitude));
 map.setZoom(15);
 
 var info = ('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '
'
   + 'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '
' + 'Altitude: '
   + position.coords.altitude + '
' + 'Accuracy: '
   + position.coords.accuracy + '
' + 'Altitude Accuracy: '
   + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '
' + 'Heading: '
   + position.coords.heading + '
' + 'Speed: '
   + position.coords.speed + '
' + 'Timestamp: ' + new Date(
   position.timestamp));
 
 var point = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
   position.coords.longitude);
 if (!marker) {
  // create marker
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position : point,
   map : map
  });
 } else {
  // move marker to new position
  marker.setPosition(point);
 }
 if (!infowindow) {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content : info
  });
 } else {
  infowindow.setContent(info);
 }
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
 });
}
 
// exit app
function exitFromApp(buttonIndex) {
 if (buttonIndex === 2) {
  navigator.app.exitApp();
 }
}
// showConfirm exit app
function showConfirm() {
 navigator.notification.confirm('Deseja Realmente Sair?', exitFromApp,
   'Geolocation Map', 'Cancelar,OK' // buttonLabels
 );
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
 content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Geolocation Maps</title>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geomap.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="index" onload="">
 
  <!-- header -->
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
   <a data-role="button" data-icon="back" onclick="showConfirm()"
    data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn-right">Sair</a>
   <h3>Geolocation Map</h3>
  </div>
 
  <!-- content #Map -->
  <div data-role="content" style="padding: 0;">
   <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
 
  <!-- footer -->
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
   <div align="center" style="font-size: 12px; color: silver;">
    <div id="infoUser"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

Fonte: [http://robsonfagundes.blogspot.com.br/](http://robsonfagundes.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/geolocalizacao-atraves-de-gps-do.html)

Comment: Claro que esse exemplo é basico mas já é um grande ponto de partida para você chegar em sua necessidade